# How do you use the phrase 留宿 （liu2su4） （i.e. “To stay over at someone's house")

Tags: vocabulary

I've been trying to figure in what contexts it is appropriate to use the term 留宿。
Is it simply staying at another person's house for the night (like in english "crashing at someone's place") or is it a bit more formal than that? 
For example, could I casually tell someone in a new city I am in.

"今天我打算在李雷家留宿？“

Comment: "宿" in "留宿" implies "night".  That's why you can say "今天我打算在李雷家留宿".

Comment: There's also 過夜, which may be less formal.  Some examples of usage here: http://www.nciku.cn/search/zh/detail/%E8%BF%87%E5%A4%9C/14764

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah it's kind of formal and "old-fashioned".

Expressing 今天我打算在李雷家留宿 more naturally can be 今天我打算住李雷家 or 今晚我打算住李雷家.

今天 in this sentence implicitly means 今晚 (tonight).

Comment: Marson, 
Do you think that using  留宿 sounds too old now? Should I just say  住A的家 when I'm talking with friends?

Comment: Yeah it is, it sounds a little funny if you talking like that, but people would understand with no problem. 留宿 is more like a word for writing, especially in old-time writings. 住A的家 is more naturally when talking.

Answer (score 1):

It means to stay over (at someone's place), and it is usually used in written form.  Therefore Marson's correct on using 今晚 instead of 今天:

今天晚上我打算在李雷家留宿

Answer (score 1):

“留宿” is more usual to be seen in a formal notice.

For example in a dormitory regulations of a Chinese university you may see:

禁止男生在女生宿舍留宿(male students are not allowed to stay in a girl's dorm overnight )